# What are all Varaha Avatars of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva-purana, varaha

In the [Chapter Manifestation of Rudra - Rudra Samhita Section one](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20655/6/Part1_Chapter4_241-320p.pdf) of Shiva Purana (Pg 224),

Brahma said this to his son Narada,

> - A boar has the power of steadily going deep below. Hence, Vishnu ,the wanderer in the forest, assumed the form of Boar.
> - Or Vishnu,the protector all the worlds assumed the form of a Boar, or start of a new Kalpa.
> - Since **the day he assumed the form a Boar, the aeon by the title of Varaha has started**.
> - Or **the Varaha Kalpa can be considered to have started since the way we decided to assume the forms**.

Similarly, in the [Chapter Story of Rsbha - Shata Rudra Samhita](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12959/3/Chapter1_1070-1148p.pdf) of Shiva Purana (Pg 1078),

Lord Shiva said,

> In the **Seventh Varaha Kalpa**, in the Vaivastara Manvantara , the
>   Lord Kalpeswara who illuminates all the worlds, will be born as your
>   great grandson and son of Vaivasvata Manu.

So there should be seven Varaha Avatars of Vishnu. I know two of them, one at time of creation and other at beginning of this Kalpa.

What are other five Varaha Avatars?

Comment: I don't think it refers to Seven Varaha Kalpas. It may just be the seventh Kalpa, which is called Varaha.

Comment: BTW, Srila Prabhupada opines (with quotes from his Sampradaya gurus) that two Varaha avataras stories were amalgamated into one - First Varaha avatara was to restore the earth, and the second to kill Hiranyaksha. Though I myself am not sure about that theory.

Comment: Plus [this page](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-83/topic-1) translates it differently: "In the **Seventh Manvantara of the Varaha Kalpa**".

Comment: Do you know chronological order of Kalpas til present Varaha Kalpa? . Shiva Purana mentions Vishnu traveled along the length of **"lingam"** for **one Kalpa**. These two are different Kalpas with same name **"Varaha"**. But what is seventh kalpa, when we have multitude of Kalpas?

Comment: It may be the seventh day of Brahma's 51st year. (As he is 51 or more years old)

Comment: @Surya According to Skanda Purana, Pitri Kalpa in which Sati died was 13th Kalpa from Creation. So, we live in 14th day of Brahma in his 51st year.

Comment: @AnilKumar Where does the Skanda Purana say that?  I'm pretty sure other Puranas say we're living in the first day of the 51st year.  And what does "13th Kalpa from Creation" mean anyway?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/27477/62f_chapter_19_1.pdf (54-56)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Which Puranas say we live in 1st day (1st Kalpa) in 51st Year of Brahma? According to Shiva Purana, Vishnu and Brahma traveled along linga for one Kalpa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like Translation error. [This page](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-83/topic-1) gives different meaning.

[image]

*Saptame caiva Varahe Kalpe* means Seventh and certainly known as Varaha Kalpa.

Caiva = ca + iva = and (also certainly).